# PLT GOT: How "jmp DWORD PTR [ebx+0xc]" takes control to GOT?

Tags: linux, debugging, intel, x86, assembly

For puts@plt, control should go from main to PLT to GOT. Control is going to PLT but from PLT how "jmp DWORD PTR [ebx+0xc]" takes control to GOT? In GDB, ebx=0, so ebx+0xc=0xc, which is weird. Where am I missing the flow?

```
└─# cat main.c                                                               
#include <stdio.h>
    
int main() {
        printf ("Hello World!\n");
        return 0;
}

└─# gcc -m32 -g main.c -o main                                               


└─# objdump -Mintel -d --no-show-raw-insn main

main:     file format elf32-i386
:::
0000119d <main>:
    119d:       lea    ecx,[esp+0x4]
    11a1:       and    esp,0xfffffff0
    11a4:       push   DWORD PTR [ecx-0x4]
    11a7:       push   ebp
    11a8:       mov    ebp,esp
    11aa:       push   ebx
    11ab:       push   ecx
    11ac:       call   11d9 <__x86.get_pc_thunk.ax>
    11b1:       add    eax,0x2e4f
    11b6:       sub    esp,0xc
    11b9:       lea    edx,[eax-0x1ff8]
    11bf:       push   edx
    11c0:       mov    ebx,eax
    11c2:       call   1030 <puts@plt>    <-- go to addr 1030 (supposed to be in PLT)
    11c7:       add    esp,0x10
    11ca:       mov    eax,0x0
    11cf:       lea    esp,[ebp-0x8]
    11d2:       pop    ecx
    11d3:       pop    ebx
    11d4:       pop    ebp
    11d5:       lea    esp,[ecx-0x4]
    11d8:       ret    

└─# objdump -Mintel -D -j main -j .plt -j .got.plt --no-show-raw-insn main   

main:     file format elf32-i386


Disassembly of section .plt:

00001020 <puts@plt-0x10>:
    1020:       push   DWORD PTR [ebx+0x4]
    1026:       jmp    DWORD PTR [ebx+0x8]
    102c:       add    BYTE PTR [eax],al
        ...

00001030 <puts@plt>:
    1030:       jmp    DWORD PTR [ebx+0xc]    <-- Go to ebx+0xc = 0xc (in gdb, ebx=0) !!
    1036:       push   0x0                        (it should have gone to GOT)
    103b:       jmp    1020 <_init+0x20>

00001040 <__libc_start_main@plt>:
    1040:       jmp    DWORD PTR [ebx+0x10]
    1046:       push   0x8
    104b:       jmp    1020 <_init+0x20>

Disassembly of section .got.plt:

00004000 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_>:
    4000:       cld    
    4001:       add    BYTE PTR ds:[eax],al
        ...
    400c:       adc    BYTE PTR ss:[eax],al
    400f:       add    BYTE PTR [esi+0x10],al
        ...
```

Comment: Note the `mov ebx,eax` right before the `call puts@plt`.  At that point, GCC has already gotten EIP into EAX and added the GOT offset.  Weird that GCC didn't just thunk into EBX in the first place like GCC traditionally did in 32-bit PIC/PIE code, before they added the ability to use other registers as the GOT pointer inside functions.  Are you sure you're seeing EBX=0 when you single-step to (or set a breakpoint on) that PLT entry?  That shouldn't happen.

Comment: Also BTW, 32-bit PIC/PIE is rather inefficient, because it lacks x86-64's RIP-relative addressing mode.  It has to do this complicated stuff to manually do relative addressing after using `call` to read the current EIP.